# SyntaxError: Unexpected token using async and babel in koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have this simple app made using the last alpha version of Koa. In order to use `async/wait Babel.Js is required.

```
'use strict';

// babel registration (runtime transpilation for node)
require('./server.babel');

const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// define logger - this will be always executed
const logger = async (context, next) => {
  const start = new Date;
  await next();
  const ms = new Date - start;
  console.log(`${context.method} ${context.url} - ${ms}ms`);
}

const index = (context) => {
  context.body = 'Hello World';
}

app.use(logger);
app.use(index);

app.listen(3000);
console.info(`The app is listening on port 3000`);
```

---

This is the hook to activate the transpiling.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let config;

try {
  config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc'));
} catch (error) {
  console.error('==>  ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
  console.error(error);
}

require('babel-core/register')(config);
```

and this is the config file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
const logger = async (context, next) => {
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:138:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

I have no idea why I get this error. I'm using the last Node.Js version `5.1.0` and Babel `6.2.1`

Comment: @Teemu typo??? where?

Comment: @Teemu string templating. new es6 feature

Comment: is your "hook" server.babel? or is that something else

Comment: my hook is inside server.babel as you may see

Comment: I'm pretty sure server.babel needs to require your app code, not the other way around.

Comment: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/api/api.js#L1

Comment: Right, but are any of the things babel is transpiling in that file? (I'm not sure, don't know exactly what the plugin they're using there does)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95721/discussion-between-mazzy-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the `SyntaxError`. That happens because your code is being parsed before Babel can intercept it and convert.

If you want to make async functions work in your first file, you should `require` this entire file after have registered its hook.

Create a new file `start.js` with the following

```
require('babel-register');
require('./index');
```

Your code in `index.js` can use async functions, but you can't do it in the `start.js`.

Also note, that you don't need to read `.babelrc` by yourself. Babel will do it for you by default.

Contents of `.babelrc` looks like this

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Reference links

- [Async Functions with Babel](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/v2.x/docs/api/index.md#async-functions-with-babel)
- [babel's require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/)

Answer (score 0):

upgrade nodejs version to v7.6.0 or higher